# Migrate a Classic Azure VM to RM in a different region and subscription

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

I have an SFTP server on a classic Azure VM running in the Southeast Asia region. I would want to migrate the VM to the resource manager version in a different subscription in the East US 2 region. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

First step is to complete the migration from Classic to ARM in the current subscription the resources are located in.

Here is the guide on how to do that: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/migration-classic-resource-manager-overview

Once the resources are migrated from Classic to ARM, you can move on to moving the resources to a new subscription.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources

So all in all, it is a 2 step process. First the Classic to ARM migration then the Subscription Migration.